# Is a sample space really necessary for this question?

Tags: probability

A game involving rolling two six-sided dice followed by rolling a third die is played - to win, the number rolled on the third die must lie between the two numbers rolled previously.

(i) What is the probability that a player has no chance of winning before rolling the third die?

(ii) What is the probability that a player wins the game?

---

I did (i) like this. $P($no chance$) = P($same numbers$) + P($consecutive numbers$)=\frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{6}$ . $\frac{5}{6}$ because none of the numbers can be 6 for next number to be "larger". This is wrong, but perhaps someone can correct my thinking?

(ii) is trickier and I cannot just do $P = 1 - P($no chance$)$ so I was wondering if there was a way around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) Your answer is a bit off. The first two dice are distinguishable — imagine one is red and one is green. The term of $\frac{1}{6}$ for the same value is fine, but the term of $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$ only counts the outcomes when the first (red) die has the smaller number and the second (green) die has the next integer. But it could be the other way around, so you need to double this term. In other words: you only counted the outcomes such as $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, and so on, but you missed outcomes such as $(2,1)$.

(ii) At first, I also thought that brute force counting was the only way to go. And it would be a little tedious, but still doable. After all, there are only six value on all dice. But then, I figured that there's a way around it.

Let's use the classical definition of probability:
$$\mathbf{Pr}\{\text{event}\}=\frac{\text{number of favorable outcomes}}{\text{number of all outcomes}}.$$

For the denominator, we're rolling three standard dice, which gives us … possible outcomes.

For the numerator, we need to count the number of ways of rolling three dice such that the value on the third is between the values on the first two. This requirement implies that the three values are different, and there are $6\choose3$ ways of picking three distinct values. The middle value is what we want to see on the third die. The other two values can appear on the first two dice in either way, so we double this number.

Comment: Ahh your solution to part ii) is ingenious!